# I can not find the `php.ini` file after I install the PHP

Tags: php

After I install the php, I can not find the `php.ini`:

```
[root@localhost html]# cd /usr/local/php-7.1.16/
[root@localhost php-7.1.16]# ls
bin  etc  include  lib  php  sbin  var
[root@localhost php-7.1.16]# find ./ -name php.ini
[root@localhost php-7.1.16]# pwd
/usr/local/php-7.1.16
```

where is the `php.ini`? I use the `./configure` installed the PHP.

In the `/usr/local/php-7.1.16/etc/`, there only the `php-fpm.*` files:

```
php-fpm.conf  php-fpm.conf.default  php-fpm.d
```

---

**EDIT-1**

I use `phpinfo();` find the `php.ini` path:

[image]

there is the `/usr/local/php-7.1.16/etc/` upper, but I did not find the `php.ini`. why?

Comment: This is very specific to your environment, without access to your PC / setup, I don't see how we can help unfortunately :S

Comment: use `sudo find / -name *.ini`

Comment: find in `xampp\php`

Comment: I think looking in `etc` is wrong, try just `/usr/local/php-7.1.16/` all of the hp configs I have seen have it within the php root, not a subdir, with that said, I am used to windows however and this looks linux-y to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as super_coder says, you have to use [`phpinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/function.phpinfo.php) to get details on the config loaded.

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

based on your phpinfo output, php is looking into `/usr/local/php-7.1.16/etc/` as the line ***configuration file path*** says.

The line ***Loaded configuration file*** says that no file is loaded so the default config is used. you can add your php.ini file in the `/usr/local/php-7.1.16/etc/` directory

You can download default config files for production or development environment on the php git repository :

- dev : https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-7.1.16/php.ini-development
- prod : https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-7.1.16/php.ini-production

Comment: which is the default config? How can I add a php.ini? copy from where? can I copy from the default config?

Comment: @qg_java_17137 see my edit for sample files. these are the default files in most php installs. just download the one that suits your needs and copy it into the config directory. (differences between the two files are mainly about error display and logging)

Comment: the github configuration file are so long.

Comment: that's because there are many comments with explanations on the configuration directives

Comment: I copy it to the php.ini, there will have more `;` for comment. so werid.

Answer (score 2):

Create a file with following code:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Execute this file and check the path of php.ini shown.

Comment: see my EDIT, friend.

Comment: As per the below "answer" - this should be a comment really, now an answer, but seeing as you have low rep, this is the only way you could help, just for future ref, something such as this, technically, doesn't attempt to answer the question, merely, provide debug aid. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `php -ini | grep Configuration` for checking:

```
# php -ini | grep Configuration
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/php-7.1.16/etc
Loaded Configuration File => (none)
Configuration
```